# Explanation of arrows in RTC flow diagram

Tags: rtc

In below diagram what is the meaning of below arrows ?

Here's what I think : 
Each arrow describes where the change sets are flowing from/to. So the top workspace flows changes and accepts changes from the stream. The bottom two workspaces just flow changes to the stream, theses workspaces do not accept any changes from the stream. Is this correct ?

What is the meaning of the broken blue arrow ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A broken arrow means: this flow target is not currently the **current one**.

If you open the stream, you will see a section "Flow Target" with a list of targets.

Each line can have two qualifier: "default" and "current".
Any target which isn't "current" will be represented by a broken arrow.

Current means that, when you are requesting to see the differences between one stream and another, it will display said differences between the stream and the **current** target.

---

See also [this thread](https://jazz.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=18428&watch=topic&start=0&sid=0b243f2e4cef0686b1b7ccd7994e22df) (more oriented for flow targets between repo workspace and streams)

> - "Current" means "this is the flow target that will be displayed in the Pending Changes view".
> - "Default" means "if you try to deliver to a flow target other than the one marked "Default", you will get a warning, asking you if you are sure that you want to deliver to a non-default target.

---

> Here's what I think : Each arrow describes where the change sets are flowing from/to.

Yes, but this is a "model": you won't directly deliver/accept changes from a Stream. You will always do so from a repo workspace.

> So the top workspace flows changes and accepts changes from the stream.

Not exactly:

- the filled blue arrow means you can ask the stream for the differences between said stream and the repo workspace (no deliver possible here, just a vizualisation of differences)
- the broken blue arrow means the repo workspace knows about the Stream (it is listed as a default flow target, but said stream **isn't the current flow target** for the top repo workspace.
  That means the "Pending Changes" views won't display any differences (to accept or to deliver) for that repo workspace compared to the Stream.

> The bottom two workspaces just flow changes to the stream, theses workspaces do not accept any changes from the stream. Is this correct ?

No: the target means the bottom repo workspaces knows about the Stream (they can accept or deliver changes), and that Stream is their *current* flow target (the "Pending changes" view actively monitor differences between the bottom repo workspace and the Stream.

Comment: Is my explanation of how each workspace/stream flows into each other correct?

Comment: @user470184 I have edited my answer to address your interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

According with link,

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/br/rational/library/parallel-development-rational-team-concert/

your assertion

> "Current" means "this is the flow target that will be displayed in the
>   Pending Changes view". "Default" means "if you try to deliver to a
>   flow target other than the one marked 'Default', you will get a
>   warning, asking you if you are sure that you want to deliver to a
>   non-default target".

is absolutely correct.